# # Unwrapping a row list before transforming it

Tags: r

I have output from older software that wraps the record for each transaction into multiple rows. I want to unwrap these rows into one flat dataframe.  I have found solutions to unwrap columns, but not rows, and can do what I need in a loop, but the output is large and I would prefer a faster solution than a loop.

Example: I read into R from a .csv file 6 pieces of information about each of two transactions ("tran") that come wrapped into four rows.

The following represents and mimics my data as I read it into R from a .csv file:

```
V1 <- c("tran1.col1", "tran1.col4","tran2.col1", "tran2.col4")
V2 <- c("tran1.col2", "tran1.col5", "tran2.col2", "tran2.col5")
V3 <- c("tran1.col3", "tran1.col6", "tran2.col3", "tran2.col6")
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(V1, V2, V3), ncol = 3))
```

I am looking to transform the above to the following:

```
X1 <- c("tran1.col1", "tran2.col1")
X2 <- c("tran1.col2", "tran2.col2")
X3 <- c("tran1.col3", "tran2.col3")
X4 <- c("tran1.col4", "tran2.col4")
X5 <- c("tran1.col5", "tran2.col5")
X6 <- c("tran1.col6", "tran2.col6")
df.x <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6), ncol = 6))
```

I've looked at tidy routines to gather and spread datafiles as well as melt and decast in reshape, but as far as I can tell, I need to unwrap the rows first.

Comment: Based on what do you want to transform the rows? Do you want all rows starting with `tran1` in row 1 and so on or you want to reduce the number of rows to half by doubling the columns ? Or some other logic?

Comment: #Ronak_Shah, yes, using the terms of the example, I want to reduce the number of rows by half by doubling the columns, though this relationship is only a function of the simplified example.  The actual situation involves thousands of rows of data each folded into 8 rows of 38 pieces of data, such that I am trying to create for each transaction one row of data consisting of 308 (=38*8) pieces of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your inputs have 6 pieces of information by however many transactions, then the following should work.

```
vec <- as.character(unlist(t(df)))
df.x <- as.data.frame(matrix(vec, ncol = 6, byrow = T))
```

To break it down to explain what's happening ...

```
# Transpose the df (to a matrix)
matrix <- t(df)

# Now that the matrix is in this sequence it will allow us to unlist it so 
# that it produces a vector in the correct sequence (i.e tran1.col1, 
# tran1.col2 .. tran2.col1, tran1.col2)
vec <- unlist(matrix)

# Now we can coerce it back to a data.frame, defining the number of columns
# and creating it by row (rather than column)
df.x <- as.data.frame(matrix(vec, ncol = 6, byrow = T))
```

Comment: #Khaynes, this works, but I'm not sure why...I'll read more about "unlist", but what is the "t" in "unlist(t(df))"?

Comment: @WBarker added to my answer to explain what it's doing.

Comment: thanks.  I'm accepting your answer because it answered by question, but I have realized my question really isn't the best way to get at my problem.  I realized that by using "scan" rather than read.csv, I can read the file as a vector and then restructure as a matrix and then a datafile.  But you gave me a good lesson on transposing and unlist!!